# ASP.Net Forms HttpClient PostAsync no response, no error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpclient

I have this code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"site_id","001"},
            {"apikey","abc01201az1024"},
            {"trans_id","45364136"},
        };

    // Get the parameters in the url encoded format
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    //Send request
    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

    DataRoot<Transaction> outPut = null;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //Get Response
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataRoot<Transaction>>(result);
    }

    return outPut;
}
```

In the debug mode at this stage, the code does not produce any response, no error code but stops running:

```
//Send request
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stop running"? Does it just stop on that line or exit completely?

Comment: On that line the app hangs for some few second , then stop . the code does not go to the next line.

Comment: But you are not doing anything with the `response` object, what do you want to happen?

Comment: i do use the response object but since at that line the process stop running , the app cant reach the others lines of codes

Comment: The response object goes out of scope immediately after it is populated, so it cannot get used outside of this snippet of code.

Comment: let me update the post for You

Comment: Is it possible to post the REST API method code as well?

Comment: i am using this method to make a request to a webservice.

Answer (score 4):

Using await like this, can end up in a deadlock.

You can use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in async methods for preventing such a deadlock.

Update code to:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

there could be a better way but this solved my problem. Call your method from another one using wait:-

```cs
public static async Task<string> AuthenticateUser()
{
    var t = Task.Run(() => ClassObject.AuthenticateUser("me"));
    t.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
    Console.ReadLine();
    return "ok";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure that it isn't actually returning the response and continuing execution?  Because the client.PostAsync() call is awaited execution may continue on a different thread.  Therefore, if you're just debugging line by line (via F10 or similar) it may appear that the method never returns; in actuality the entire method has finished execution and your program is running.

You may need to add another breakpoint in the method (after the PostAsync method call).  When the PostAsync method returns on a different thread, your debugger should hit the next breakpoint.